# A question of quasi-isometric of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

For two free groups with finite ranks, are they quasi-isometric to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that $F_{nm+1}$ is a subgroup of $F_{n+1}$ of index $m$, which implies that for any $n, m$ we have that $F_{nm+1}$ is quasi-isometric to $F_{n+1}$. In particular, setting $n = 1$ gives that all free groups of finite rank at least $2$ are quasi-isometric to $F_2$ and hence to each other. ($F_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is not quasi-isometric to the others.)

Comment: Thank you, I wonder how to show the claim you used: Every group is quasi-isometric to any subgroup of finite index?

Comment: nice..................+1

Comment: @Katherine: If you have a followup question, it is better to post it as a different question. However, to avoid the question being closed, it is good to include your thoughts about the question, including what you have tried, where you got stuck, and so on.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you.